# Handsontable is displaying full date instead of dateFormat

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am using Handsontable  http://handsontable.com/  to creating spreadsheets. I am getting data from database and displaying it. But it is displaying date in below format.

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

While i have used that.

```
{type: 'date', dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY', correctFormat: true},
```

please have a look on it.
http://jsfiddle.net/HFBS6/

Answer (score 3):

Handsontable does not format date strings with `dateFormat` property, you need to supply formatted date in data object, or create custom `DateRender` method where you will parse date value.